Dependency Scanning not running
we are trying to create requirements.txt file via the pipeline job generate-requirements before running the "dependency_scanning" stage. This stage
needs the requirements.txt file as an artifact.For some reason this stage dependency_scanning is not running. Does anyone know why it is not running?
Stages:
- generate-requirements
- test 

- template: Security/Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
  DS_EXCLUDED_ANALYZERS: ""
  DS_EXCLUDED_PATHS: "spec, test, tests, tmp"

generate-requirements:
  stage: generate-requirements
  image: "python:latest"
  script:
    - pip install pipreqs
    - pipreqs .
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - requirements.txt

dependency_scanning:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - generate-requirements
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - gl-sbom-*.cdx.json
    reports:
      dependency_scanning:
        - gl-sbom-*.cdx.json

